# import javax.xml.xpath cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, xml

I can't use the different imports

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
```

I use android 1.5

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Android 1.5 does not support XPath. Only Android 2.2 and up do. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) is the docs page. The minimum Android API level for XPath is 8, which is Android 2.2 . So you're either going to have to find another way to parse XML ([SAX](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) runs on ALL Android versions) or update your project to 2.2. [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) are the stats to about how many users are there for each Android version. The majority is Android 2.2

Comment: I'm advanced in my project and i must read data with xpath from an xml file

Comment: @user616263 Then you have to update your project's minSdkVersion to 8.

Answer (score 0):

XPath was introduced in SDK 8(2.2). http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Upgrade your SDK and use it.